# React Hooks - Using lodash's deepCopy not causing re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, lodash

I'm using React.js with hooks and trying to change a nested state value.
Since I don't want to mutate the state directly, I'm using lodash's "CloneDeep" function.
The state changes successfully, but a re-render doesn't happen so I don't see the change in the page until I re-enter it.
More info (checks results in my web console):
`console.log(logicalLinesDeepCopy == logicalLines);` => false
`console.log(logicalLinesDeepCopy === logicalLines);` => false
`console.log(logicalLines[menuLineId].content[menuSentenceId].triggers);` => []
`console.log(logicalLinesDeepCopy[menuLineId].content[menuSentenceId].triggers);` => [(object)]

My code:

```
// relevant imports:
import CloneDeep from "lodash/cloneDeep";

// relevant state initiation: (the value is filled before I call the relevant function)
const [logicalLines, setLogicalLines] = useState(null);

// relevant function:
const addTriggerToListInState = (trigger) => {
    // Deep copy:
    let logicalLinesDeepCopy = CloneDeep(logicalLines);
    // Change the deep copy:
    const lineCopy = logicalLinesDeepCopy[menuLineId];
    const triggersListCopy = lineCopy.content[menuSentenceId].triggers;
    triggersListCopy.push(trigger);
    // Some debug checks:
    console.log(logicalLinesDeepCopy == logicalLines);
    console.log(logicalLinesDeepCopy === logicalLines);
    console.log(logicalLines[menuLineId].content[menuSentenceId].triggers);
    console.log(logicalLinesDeepCopy[menuLineId].content[menuSentenceId].triggers);
    // Setting the state:
    setLogicalLines(logicalLinesDeepCopy);
  };
```

So it looks like both the reference and the nested content of the new state are different from the previous one, then why doesn't it cause a re-render and how can I change it to cause it?

Thanks!

Sapir

Comment: I suspect the component doesn't render from another reason, please make a minimal and reproducible example (https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-react-template-irhcq) [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: If what you put in setLogicalLines is different than the previous value then it does re-render. try adding `{json.stringify(logicalLines)}` in your jsx so you cna be sure your values are differents

Comment: @DennisVash You're right, thanks. Using your link to the sandbox, I've created a minimal reproducible example and the re-render did happen. I'll check other reasons for it not re-rendering in my code.